# Generating screenshots in Java&TestNG with Allure reporting

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, allure

I'm setting up the reporting for automated tests with Allure & TestNG on Java. Everything works fine, just wondering if any of you tried to generate screenshots in Allure report. Where do I need to set the code responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

since there's a selenium tag on your question i assume you can use it.
my solution is divided into:

1. taking a screen-shot using selenium. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)
2. add the shot as an attachment of the report.  [see TestNg section at allure docs](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/)

in my (python) code it looks like:

```
def AttachScreenshot(picName='Screenshot'):
    """
    add screenshot to current step at allure
    """
    Webdriver = GetDriver()
    allure.attach(Webdriver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name=picName, attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```